# WyUpdate - C# Console application, update not responding working... how to run synchronous?

Tags: c#, console-application, synchronous, wyupdate

If anyone has any feedback on why my WyUpdate application doesn't want to work please let me know.

I'm trying to create a basic console application which launches the WyUpdate process, and then on completion executes my main application (which has just been updated).

Following the instructions on http://wyday.com/wybuild/help/silent-update-windows-service.php gives me no luck at all.  The application runs, and executes the "ForceCheckForUpdate" process, but I don't receive any feedback :(

here is a complete listing of my code.

I've added a while loop to hopefully catch the response from the auBackend, but that doesn't seem to work.  is there an easy way to run the process synchronously and wait for the response before closing the application?

Thanks in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using wyDay.Controls;
```

namespace NPS.CeAUpdateLauncher
{
    class Program
    {
        private static AutomaticUpdaterBackend auBackend;
        private static bool receivedFeedback;

`static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        auBackend = new AutomaticUpdaterBackend
        {
            //TODO: set a unique string.
            // For instance, "appname-companyname"
            GUID = "CeALauncher_AutoUpdate",

            // With UpdateType set to Automatic, you're still in
            // charge of checking for updates, but the
            // AutomaticUpdaterBackend continues with the
            // downloading and extracting automatically.
            UpdateType = UpdateType.Automatic,
        };

        auBackend.CheckingFailed += auBackend_CheckingFailed;
        auBackend.UpdateAvailable += auBackend_UpdateAvailable;
        auBackend.DownloadingFailed += auBackend_DownloadingFailed;
        auBackend.ExtractingFailed += auBackend_ExtractingFailed;
        auBackend.ReadyToBeInstalled += auBackend_ReadyToBeInstalled;
        auBackend.UpdateSuccessful += auBackend_UpdateSuccessful;
        auBackend.UpdateFailed += auBackend_Failed;

        // Initialize() and AppLoaded() must be called after events have been set.
        // Note: If there's a pending update to be installed, wyUpdate will be
        //       started, then it will talk back and say "ready to install,
        //       you can close now" at which point your app will be closed.
        auBackend.Initialize();
        auBackend.AppLoaded();


        if (!auBackend.ClosingForInstall)
        {
            //TODO: do your normal service work
            CheckForUpdates();
        }            

        //
        while(!receivedFeedback)
            Thread.Sleep(10000);

    }

    static void CheckForUpdates()
    {
        // Only ForceCheckForUpdate() every N days!
        // You don't want to recheck for updates on every app start.

        if (//(DateTime.Now - auBackend.LastCheckDate).TotalDays > 10 &&
            auBackend.UpdateStepOn == UpdateStepOn.Nothing)
        {
            auBackend.ForceCheckForUpdate();

        }
    }

    static void auBackend_CheckingFailed(object sender, FailArgs e)
    {
        receivedFeedback = true;
    }

    static void auBackend_UpdateAvailable(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        receivedFeedback = true;
    }

    static void auBackend_DownloadingFailed(object sender, FailArgs e)
    {
        receivedFeedback = true;
    }

    static void auBackend_ExtractingFailed(object sender, FailArgs e)
    {
        receivedFeedback = true;
    }

    static void auBackend_ReadyToBeInstalled(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ReadyToBeInstalled event is called when
        // either the UpdateStepOn == UpdateDownloaded or UpdateReadyToInstall

        if (auBackend.UpdateStepOn == UpdateStepOn.UpdateReadyToInstall)
        {
            //TODO: Delay the installation of the update until
            //      it's appropriate for your app.

            //TODO: Do any "spin-down" operations. auBackend.InstallNow() will
            //      exit this process using Environment.Exit(0), so run
            //      cleanup functions now (close threads, close running programs,
            //      release locked files, etc.)

            // here we'll just close immediately to install the new version
            auBackend.InstallNow();
        }
        receivedFeedback = true;

    }

    static void auBackend_UpdateSuccessful(object sender, SuccessArgs e)
    {
        receivedFeedback = true;
    }

    static void auBackend_Failed(object sender, FailArgs e)
    {
        receivedFeedback = true;
    }



}`

}

Comment: Is the console just dropping out immediately or does it seem to be checking for the update then dropping out?

Comment: The console just runs indefinitely.  I found that I never handled the "UpToDate" event and thus the indicator was never set to allow the program to exit, eventhough the wyUpdate returned a response.

An alternative way of waiting for the response has been shown in my post below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the code I attached in my initial post, the problem was that the console application would be running indefinitely.  I thought that was because the wyUpdate process never returned a value.  I found out it was because I didn't raise all events.

After implementing the eventhandler for "UpToDate" I received a response and was able to set the indicator to have the application exit successfully.

I also replaced the boolean indicator and the 'while' method of waiting for a response to the 'resetEvent' as per the vendor's instructions, and it is working very well.

```
static readonly ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          ...
          auBackend.UpToDate += auBackend_UpToDate;
          ...

          // Blocks until "resetEvent.Set()" on another thread
          resetEvent.WaitOne();

        }

static void auBackend_UpToDate(object sender, SuccessArgs e)
        {
            resetEvent.Set();
        }
```

Thanks for the responses.

If anyone ever needs a very versatile application updater solution, I would suggest the wyBuild/wyUpdate package.

Njoy!

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to use the [Reactive Extensions for .NET (Rx)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/threads) then I've got an easier alternative.

As long as the `AutomaticUpdaterBackend` class is firing its events on a background thread then this code should do what you want:

```
void Main(string[] args)
{
    var auBackend = new AutomaticUpdaterBackend
    {
        GUID = "CeALauncher_AutoUpdate",
        UpdateType = UpdateType.Automatic,
    };

    var checkingFailed = Observable.FromEvent<FailArgs>(h => auBackend.CheckingFailed += h, h => auBackend.CheckingFailed -= h);
    var updateAvailable = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(h => auBackend.UpdateAvailable += h, h => auBackend.UpdateAvailable -= h);
    var downloadingFailed = Observable.FromEvent<FailArgs>(h => auBackend.DownloadingFailed += h, h => auBackend.DownloadingFailed -= h);
    var extractingFailed = Observable.FromEvent<FailArgs>(h => auBackend.ExtractingFailed += h, h => auBackend.ExtractingFailed -= h);
    var readyToBeInstalled = Observable.FromEvent<EventArgs>(h => auBackend.ReadyToBeInstalled += h, h => auBackend.ReadyToBeInstalled -= h);
    var updateSuccessful = Observable.FromEvent<SuccessArgs>(h => auBackend.UpdateSuccessful += h, h => auBackend.UpdateSuccessful -= h);
    var updateFailed = Observable.FromEvent<FailArgs>(h => auBackend.UpdateFailed += h, h => auBackend.UpdateFailed -= h);

    var readyToBeInstalledStepReady = readyToBeInstalled.Where(e => auBackend.UpdateStepOn == UpdateStepOn.UpdateReadyToInstall);
    var readyToBeInstalledStepNotReady = readyToBeInstalled.Where(e => auBackend.UpdateStepOn != UpdateStepOn.UpdateReadyToInstall);

    var failed = Observable.Merge(new []
    {
        checkingFailed.Select(e => "Checking Failed"),
        downloadingFailed.Select(e => "Downloading Failed"),
        extractingFailed.Select(e => "Extracting Failed"),
        updateFailed.Select(e => "Update Failed"),
        readyToBeInstalledStepNotReady.Select(e => "Update Not Ready"),
    });

    var success = Observable.Merge(new []
    {
        readyToBeInstalledStepReady.Select(e => "Update Ready"),
        updateSuccessful.Select(e => "Update Successful"),
    });;

    failed.Subscribe(e => Console.Error.WriteLine(e));
    success.Subscribe(e => Console.WriteLine(e));

    readyToBeInstalledStepReady.Subscribe(e => auBackend.InstallNow());

    auBackend.Initialize();
    auBackend.AppLoaded();

    if (!auBackend.ClosingForInstall)
    {
        if (auBackend.UpdateStepOn == UpdateStepOn.Nothing)
        {
            auBackend.ForceCheckForUpdate();
        }
    }            

    success.Merge(failed).First();
}
```

Yes, there aren't any module-level variables and no event handler methods. Just locals and lambdas. :-)

Comment: Hi Enigmativity, 
thanks for your response.  Before reading your post I received word back from the vendor, and I implemented their solution which was a lot less changes than changing the code to yours.  Also, all the observable's and merges and event usages you supplied are a bit over my head, but thanks anyway :)

The solution I used is explained below